# I want a thin border doughnut chart

Tags: javascript, html, css

I want a thin border chart.

```
<canvas id="chart-area" width="200" height="200" style="width:150px !important; height:150px !important;"/></canvas>
```

Script is here:

```
<script src="[http://www.chartjs.org/assets/Chart.min.js][1]"></script>

<script>
    var doughnutData = [
            {
                value: 45,
                color:"#17CB8A",
                highlight: "#17CB8C",
                label: "Strating",
            },

        ];

        window.onload = function(){
            var ctx = document.getElementById("chart-area").getContext("2d");
            window.myDoughnut = new Chart(ctx).Doughnut(doughnutData, {responsive : true});

</script>
```

I want a very thin border.

Comment: please explain what you want. Which border?

Comment: I want that Green Color border very thin in size. like o

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you have to set that with the property: `percentageInnerCutout : 80`

With that property you can set how big the green border should be if I understand it correctly. For example, if you can change the value from `80` to `0` you will get a piechart.

code:

```
var data = [{
            value: 45,
            color:"#17CB8A",
            highlight: "#17CB8C",
            label: "Strating"                
        }

]

var options = {
    animation: false,
    percentageInnerCutout : 80
};
```

Check out this [JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/2uwLpvkb/)

---

**EDIT FULL CODE:**

HTML CODE:

```
<canvas id="myChart" width="200" height="200" style="width:150px !important; height:150px !important;"></canvas>
```

JS CODE:

```
var data = [{
            value: 45,
            color:"#17CB8A",
            highlight: "#17CB8C",
            label: "Strating"                
        }

]

var options = {
    animation: false,
    percentageInnerCutout : 80
};

//Get the context of the canvas element we want to select
var c = $('#myChart');
var ct = c.get(0).getContext('2d');
var ctx = document.getElementById("myChart").getContext("2d");
/*************************************************************************/
myNewChart = new Chart(ct).Doughnut(data, options);
```

Comment: what is not working? the JSFIDDLE works. just look at my JSFIDDLE why does that not work?